# shorth function in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to reproduce an analysis (a transcriptomic analysis) that I found in a research paper. The methods section says:

> After normalization an expression threshold for each cell line was
>   calculated to get rid of low intensity probes that can be considered
>   technical noise. First, probe sets were sorted by increasing
>   expression value. For each probe set a t-test was performed to
>   evaluate the differential expression between this probe set and the
>   median value of the probe sets with less expression values.

I've used the shorth function in R in order to reproduce this analysis, I would like to know if you consider that is a appropriate method.

My data is from Affymetrix Hugene 1.1 st array. After normalization using RMA *(dat)* I executed the following code to obtain the less expressed probe sets:

```
  med.exp <- rowMedians(exprs(dat))
  med <- shorth(med.exprs)
```

And then, I calculated a `t.test` for comparing each probe sets with the *med* value

```
 tt <- rep(0.8256, 23) ## 0.8256 is the value of *shorth(med.exprs)* and I have 23 samples
 result.pvalue <- sapply(1:nrow(myAB1_rma.exprs), function(i) t.test(dat[i,], tt))
```

Could be this approach valid?

Many thanks in advance,

Juan

Comment: I think this is a statistical question, which belongs on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) and should be moved there.

Comment: Thanks Backlin, I´ll move the question to Cross Validated, many thanks

Comment: Link to version of this question on Cross Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/37902/5880